Is "die Jeans" ever used in the singular?
Duolingo seems to show the noun "die Jeans" as a plurale tantum, namely a noun without a singular form, like in English. These sentences are from a Duolingo story where a father and a son discuss a pair of jeans:

Probiere wenigstens diese Jeans an.
Junior probiert die Jeans an und zeigt sie Eddy. "Ich hasse sie."
"Die Jeans sind super, oder?" "Sie sind okay."
"Meine alten Jeans sind viel besser."

Wiktionary doesn't have much information on this but does list the singular form in its declension table. Duden seems to suggest either way is fine:

Wo sind/ist denn bloß meine alten/alte Jeans?

So is a pair of jeans grammatically plural like English "jeans" or singular like "die Hose"?

According to random internet sites, "Jeans" is derived from the French name for the Italian city of Genua, Gênes (which allegedly exported a vaguely similar type of trousers). If that were true (I have not tried to fact check), "Jeans" would not be a plural at all.

@EikePierstorff That is actually correct: https://www.dwds.de/wb/Jeans

"Die Jean(s)" is most probably a singular, mistaken to be a plural.
The source of the problem is that what "hose(n)" (originally also the English term) is/are changed through history: in the beginning (~13th century upwards) a "hose" was a tube of cloth for one leg. The word is derived from germanic "husõn" (old High German "hosa", Middle High German "hose") , which probably meant the rags made from cloth or leather bound around the lower legs. You needed two of them, one for each leg and they were not connected in the crotch - similar to "chaps", a protective garment used in horse riding. This tubular form is where the term "hose" with the meaning "tube for transporting water" comes from and also why "(pair of) trousers" in English is a plural word. You also see the old word "hose" in compounds like "pantyhose".
In the 17th century wearing "hosen" (the old English plural) fell out of fashion and breeches plus stockings were being worn instead. Only in later times "trousers" - "hosen" but with an added middle piece to cover the crotch - made a comeback.
Because of this development the word "trousers" in English is still a plural although today it is one piece of garment and similar in German there is "die Hose" (singular) but also "die Hosen" (plural) to denote a single piece although the older plural form is falling out of use in favour of the singular. Without being able to proof that my suspicion is that "die Hosen" is more common in the northern part of the German-speaking area while the singular "die Hose" is more common in the south.
For instance there is the proverbial

die Hosen anhaben

for "being the one to call the shots" where the plural is used.
Most probably this is why "jeans" (a sort of trousers) is also plural in English and why in German "Jeans" is used as a singular as well as a plural but also "Jean" as a singular is (less commonly) in use. Using your example:

Meine alten Jeans sind viel besser.
Meine alte Jeans ist viel besser.
Meine alte Jean ist viel besser.

are arguably all correct although perhaps only one of them is common in any certain area.

I grew up in the North and I never heard "die Hosen" used as singular.

@planetmaker: no, "die Hosen" is plural, "die Hose" is singular.

Never have I came across "Jean". Source?

"Hosen" was used as a singular when I grew up. More relevant, there are at least archaic uses - the Tirso de Molina play is e.g. translated as "Don Gil von den grünen Hosen", even though Doña Juana's male disguise comprises only one pair of trousers.

Also regarding the singular "Jean", German Wikipedia claims that is is used in Austria (can't confirm this from my own conversations with Austrians, though).

'For instance there is the proverbial "die Hosen anhaben" for "being the one to call the shots" where the plural is used.' - even that is not clear-cut. Granted, historically, you're probably right. But with the contemporary (more commonly singular) use of the word, I have always understood that expression as talking about all the "Hosen" that the person owns and wears day after day, but only one "Hose" at a time.

Wiktionary suggests that "Hose" is derived from the Old High German word for "stocking" and that "Hosen"  is a valid singular because the thing bascially comprises two stockings (and some connective tissue). https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Hose.

You wanna make a claim about Jeans but talk exclusively about Hosen. I do believe that Jeans is singular, but for a different reason - the etymology of the word.

I've never ever met anyone using the quasi-singular "Jean" for  trousers. Jean is a french surname.

Yes. Actually, it's more commonly used in singular than plural. But how to tell that for a feminine noun which is the same in singular and plural?
Through dative case.

An dieser Jeans ist alles kaputt. (chiefly)
An diesen Jeans ist alles kaputt. (not that common)


Declension
The noun »Jeans« is one of the very rare examples of feminine nouns that do not change at all when declined for case or number. (In fact, it's the only noun I know that behaves this way, not counting compound nouns like Bluejeans or Karottenjeans.) Only its article changes, and you can also tell the grammatical number from verbs in relative clauses that refer to this noun.



Case
Singular
Plural




Nom.
Die Jeans, die ich gerade anhabe, ist aus Baumwolle.
Die Jeans, die in meinem Schrank hängen, sind alle aus Baumwolle.


Gen.
Die Farbe der Jeans, die ich gerade anhabe, ist dunkelblau.
Die Farben der Jeans, die in meinem Schrank hängen, sind unterschiedlich.


Dat.
Das häufige Waschen hat der Jeans nicht gut getan.
Das häufige Waschen hat den Jeans nicht gut getan.


Akk.
Ich trage die Jeans, die ich gerade anhabe, sehr gerne.
Ich trage die Jeans, die in meinem Schrank hängen, sehr gerne.



Note, that in Austrian German also the singular Form »die Jean« exists as commonly used alternative form to »die Jeans«. (Later is correct in the whole German speaking area.) So, these are correct sentences in Austrian German:


Die Jean, die ich gerade anhabe, ist aus Baumwolle.
Die Farbe der Jean, die ich gerade anhabe, ist dunkelblau.
Das häufige Waschen hat der Jean nicht gut getan.
Ich trage die Jean, die ich gerade anhabe, sehr gerne.



Plural usage for one item
In English, you wear trousers, jeans and glasses. These are names for items that consist of two mirrored parts, such as the left and right legs of a pair of trousers or jeans, or the left and right lenses of a pair of glasses. In German it's similar, but in German you have the choice if you use the singular or the plural form for one thing. So these are correct sentences:

Ich trage heute die Brillen mit dem blauen Bügel.
Ich trage heute die Brille mit dem blauen Bügel.
Kevin ist in kurzen Hosen zum Vorstellungsgespräch gekommen.
Kevin ist in einer kurzen Hose zum Vorstellungsgespräch gekommen.
Kevin ist in schwarzen Jeans zum Vorstellungsgespräch gekommen.
Kevin ist in einer schwarzen Jeans zum Vorstellungsgespräch gekommen.
Kevin ist in einer schwarzen Jean zum Vorstellungsgespräch gekommen. (Austrian German)

